# TinyMCE 4 custom styles

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

My problem is that i need to apply custom css to tinyMCE, but they just dont get picked up.
I've tried replacing the default styles as well as, but it still loads them from somewhere else.

According to their docs I can use "content_css" to apply my custom styles, but that didn't work too.

Any ideas how I can apply the styles?

This is my config:

```
$(".type").tinymce({
    plugins : 'advlist autolink link lists',
    theme: "modern",
    skin: 'test',
    content_css:"/static/js/general/tinymce/skins/test/custom.css",
    inline:true,
    menubar:false,
});
```

Comment: `content_css` is the way, and I'm certain it works. Make sure your path to the css file is correct and also try clearing cache/hitting the refresh button.

Comment: you might wanna try using an absolute path for the css file

Comment: an interesting thing i noticed is that it has it cached somewhere or loads the style remotely because i had the css formatted but it still had the minified ver and i even tried deleting it but it still found it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered that using the `skin` property on the init
the skin CSS loaded  through there will override local

I'm not sure (haven't tested yet) but like me, you're probably loading the tinymce stuff after on the end of the `<body>` so the tinymce will load the css files

- `<path-to-tinymce-js>/skins/<your-skin-name>/content.min.css`
- `<path-to-tinymce-js>/skins/<your-skin-name>/skin.min.css`

Imaging that tinymce js is in `assets/tinymce`the files it will load are:

- `assets/tinymce/skins/test/content.min.css`
- `assets/tinymce/skins/test/skin.min.css`

so these are loaded after the ones defined on `<head>`

But if everything else fails:
I've hard coded the css changes into `skin.min.css`...

**Notice!**

I still use the `content_css` to change css in the `<iframe>` (example: fonts, background color, ...)

Comment: Ah I had forgotten about this question, I also ended up using this method. Good call!